# news gk4 doesn't work with arabic in normal mode

Tags: joomla2.5

am using joomla 2.5. i installed News Show Pro GK4 ver. 3.3.8 and it works fine for english and french language but not very good with arabic (RTL). width arabic it works fine with all Module mode except with normal mode, it shows a blank space instead of the articles.
here is the link of the module :[Module link](http://www.gavick.com/news-show-pro-gk4.html)
link of the page : [page link](http://hop4job.com/index.php/ar/2013-07-15-09-13-58/buanderie.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not exactly sure why this happens. If you open Chrome Dev Tools or Firebug etc you will see the following at the top:

```
<html lang="" dir="rtl" >
```

changing `rtl` to `ltr` as you will see fixes the problem, however only temporarily.

What you can do is detect if the site is being viewed in a RTL language and if so, use some css:

```
<?php
   $rtl = JFactory::getLanguage()->isRTL();
   $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
   if ($rtl) {
       $doc->addStyleDeclaration(" .nspMain { direction: ltr; } ");
   }
?>
```

Rather than editing the module itself or the template *index.php* file, I would suggest making a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core).

It's not the most efficient fix, however till I found out why it actually happens, it's all I can provide.

Hope it helps